# In laravel, can I use accessor in controller or is there a better way to do it what I want to happen?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

**Context:**
So let's say I have 3 tables: Genres, Books, Authors
and Each Book has a Genre and Author(s).

What I want to happen is return a list of Genres with all the related Books with Authors. Basically, group Books by Genre and include book authors. This is what I'm doing.

```
Genre->with(['books' => function($q) { $query->with('authors'); }]);
```

Problem I'm having is the speed since I have a lot of books and double that number is the number of authors. The speed is okay when Authors is not included and adds around 4sec when included which is not good since I just need the name of the Author - sometimes just one Author when the book has multiple author.

I'm thinking of creating an accessor in Books model to get just get the name of one Author related to it. I'm still figuring out how to do it and how I can append that accessor in controller because I don't want to use the protected $appends since it is not always needed.

Do you think it is better to use accessor or is there a better way to do what I wanted to happen?

Comment: How do your relationships in these 3 models look like ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could adjust authors relationship to always return just one author (modify orderBy clause as needed).

```
$genre = Genre->with(['books.authors' => function($query) { 
    $query->orderBy('name')->limit(1); 
}])->first();
```

And when fetching the author, you can assume that first entry is the one you need.

```
$genre->books->each(function (Book $book) {
    $book->title; 
    $book->authors->first()->name; 
});
```

To increase performance, make sure that your foreign keys ar indexed.